# How to convert an array of pixel values(greyscale) to an image in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing

I have pixel values(greyscale, alpha = 255) for an image of size 400x400 in a 1D array. I want to actually make this image out of the pixel data.

What I exactly want is that I have this array -> `[some greyscale pixel values]`, and I want to create an image file/object out of it in **Node.js**.

The file type of the image does not matter.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please show an example of your array and the desired result

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bmp-js. Or you can go nerd mode and create it yourself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format